# Getting error on PSConfig - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, search-results, psconfig

I am trying to run this command `PsConfig -cmd secureresources` in the Windows PowerShell ISE. But I am getting following errors:

> Psconfig: The term 'Psconfig' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again...

The reason I am running this command so I can fix the search indexing issues which is explained in this forum:

http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/SharePoint-Error-The-search-application-on-server-did-not-finish-loading-View-the-event-logs-on-the-affected-server-for-more-information

Can you please help me to sort this issue out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the SharePoint Management Shell instead which has pathing for psconfig, but instead, use PowerShell. `Initialize-SPResourceSecurity` is the replacement for that specific command.

Comment: So you mean i can use Windows power shell and run this command instead? Initialize-SPResourceSecurity?

Comment: You can use the SharePoint Management Shell, or if you use the standard Windows PowerShell, you need to first run `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell` in order to load the SharePoint PowerShell module. But yes, you can (should) use that cmdlet instead.